# I'm replacing the bathroom fan/light switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image]

I replaced the bathroom light/fan switch just as it came out.
The issue that I encountered was when I powered on the switch both the light and fan came on.
I noticed as in the attached pictures there is a jumper wire connecting both terminals on one side of the switch.
I would think this was the problem, but I replaced the switch exactly as the old switch.
Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this and having problems posting.

Comment: I do not see third insulated wire(black) from the cable.  On that side of the switch the two screws seem to be connected with the tab, so the jumper is not needed.  You should have two wires on the other side, fan and light(switched hots),If the black screws are the hot.  A picture showing the other side will help also.

Comment: Both switches don't work independently of each other.

Comment: The switch seems wired correctly.  To get picky, the only wrong thing is the hot white wire not being marked. as hot.  That switch should work correctly, so the problem might be at the fan/light.

Comment: That is the problem. I didn't touch the fan wiring and now I have this issue. Thanks for the imput.

Comment: I would remove the jumper since it is unneeded and those screws are the one screw, one wire type, not two wire type.  If the new switch has the tab between the screws.

Answer (score 1):

Dual switches like this are designed to switch two different loads. The internal configuration of the switch works like this:

[image]

The screws on the sides across from each switch connect to their respective upper or lower switch.

Some types of these switches are designed such that it is possible to power two loads from a single power source wire and thus are provided with a jumper tab that connects two of the screws (illustrated above via the orange line on the side of the switch). This tab is designed to be removable via a breakaway to isolate the two switches should that be necessary for a particular application.

On your switch this tab is identified by the green circle below. The jumper wire, which I drew a blue line upon, appears unnecessary because the tab discussed above looks to be intact.

[image]

**Added Information**

Now that you added an additional picture of the other side of the switch it appears that the wiring configuration here is one where the AC power source is in the ceiling electrical box and connects to a common power connection on your fan/light fixture (likely the black wire in the ceiling incoming cable). The white wire in the ceiling box incoming cable is connected to the white wire in the three wire cable coming to the switch box. The red and black wires in that cable are likely connected to the separate light and fan wires in the fixture and then come down to the switch where the can be switched to the neutral white to connect to each separate switch. The switch looks wired correctly (with the jumper being redundant as discussed above).

What you need to check out is your fan fixture and its installation instructions sheet. It is likely that there is a switch or jumper wire type connection in the fixture that defaults to allowing both the fan and light to operate from one switch. (Such installation then often then relies on the pull chains from the fixture to provide fan control whilst the light is on). When you check this out you may very well find out why both switches operate both the fan and the light.

Comment: I wired this switch just as the old switch was and now the new switch runs both the fan and the light at the same time.

Comment: I read that already in your question!

Comment: How about a pic of the new switch.

Comment: Both switches are identical. I will have to remove the switch to take that picture.

Comment: I added additional information to my answer which probably provides an explanation of what is going on with your fan/light fixture.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Any idea how that could have changed by replacing the bathroom switch?

Comment: Without knowing how it is wired at the fan, I think it is an old style switch loop with /3 cable.  If so the white should be connected to the hot in the ceiling.

Comment: I believe what happened here is the black jumper wire was put on the wrong side of the switch, so that whenever any switch is on it sends power to both fan and light.  A  pic of the new switch could confirm that.

Comment: @RMDman  With the tab between the two screws, the black jumper is just a second unneeded path.

Comment: @ crip659, I understand that...however the OP stated that he wired the new switch exactly as the old one.  If he used the jumper wire, but on the wrong side he will get the results he is getting.

Comment: Today I will be investigating the fan box. As I said before I was very careful to replace the wires exactly as they came off, so the story continues. Thanks for your continued help.